# Bounded perturbation of a skew adjoint operator generates a strongly continuous group?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A: D(A)\subset X \to X$ be a skew adjoint operator and $B: X\to X$ be a bounded operator. We know that $A$ generates a group of continuous operators $S(t)$. I guess $A+B$ also generates a group of continuous operators. How do we approach this?